# PHP 7.2 Upgrade Code - REGEX Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, regex, constants, upgrade, php-7.2

atm i want to prepare my code to upgrade from `PHP 7.0 to 7.2.`
For this i wrote my own small search & replace script which uses REGEX rules to find incompatiblity code and if possible fix them with preg_replace.

**Code Error:**

> "Warning: Use of undefined constant..."

For this i wrote the follow REGEX:

```
$search_strings['7.0 to 7.2']['search'][]   = '#(\[([^0-9$]\w+)\](?!\'))#i'; 
$search_strings['7.0 to 7.2']['replace'][]  = '[\'$2\']';
```

This works with normal Arrays in code but if they are nested inside a MySQL Query or inside a echo/declaration value it still sucks:

The most rules worked fine, but now i want to fix the follow:

```
$MyArray[array_level1][] = 'sdfsdf [test] my code';
```

will replace to(wrong):

```
$MyArray['array_level1'][] = 'sdfsdf ['test'] my code';
```

should be:

```
$MyArray['array_level1'][] = 'sdfsdf [test] my code';
```

or

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM $tbl[my_table_name] WHERE request LIKE '$myArray[test]%' LIMIT 0,1";
```

will replace to(wrong):

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM $tbl['my_table_name'] WHERE request LIKE '$myArray['test']%' LIMIT 0,1";
```

should be(i think for this is an extra regex needed because to complex?):

```
$sel = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbl['my_table_name']." WHERE request LIKE '".$myArray['test']."%' LIMIT 0,1";
```

Which also wrong...i testet several REGEX but didn´t find a solution, i think i need to optimize my negative lookahead, here is my example:

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/ghlpAx/3)

Comment: You could replace `'".$myArray['test']."%'` by simply `{$myArray['test']}%` in you last case / idem for `".$tbl['my_table_name']."` ->  `{$tbl['my_table_name']}`

Comment: Anf for your first case, why are you adding quotes in the replacement string if you don't want them...? (`'[\'$2\']';`)

Comment: in my first case i want them, but only in `$MyArray['array_level1'][]` not in the last part...`= 'sdfsdf ['test'] my code';`

Comment: for the last case, this is a good idea and i will try to catch this with an extra regex for mysql queries. TY! If i have a solution i will post this here.